# How can I tell when the last row of a ListView data source is being bound?

Tags: asp.net, data-binding

I have a nested ListView control and within the ItemTemplate I need to make a call to a method in the code-behind file in order to apply a different CSS class to the final row in the rendered table.

I am calling the method as follows...

```
<td class="<%# GetClass(Container) %>">
```

Container gives me the ListViewDataItem that is being bound so I was thinking that I can check this item against the list view data source to see if it is the last item in the data source, but how do I get to the data source of the nested control?

Is there a better way of achieving this, I know it could be done with jquery but I was hoping for a C#/ASP.net solution. Thanks.

Comment: Are you using OnItemDataBound events in both ListViews?

Comment: No I'm not using them at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I solved it...

```
protected string GetClass(ListViewDataItem container)
{
    List<IIndividualNetworkLevel3Word> dataSource = (List<IIndividualNetworkLevel3Word>)(((ListView)container.BindingContainer).DataSource);

    if (container.DataItemIndex == dataSource.Count-1)
    {
        return string.Empty;
    }

    return "customGridItems";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try the OnItemDataBound event of the nested one, then keep a counter running, if counter == DataSource.Count, set the td's class.